# tTorrent client error

Tags: java, file, bittorrent

I'm trying to implement the tTorrent client into my program, I've looked at this link for an example (https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent/issues/16)  and placed that code into the Download class of my program. Here is the code:

import statements:

```
import main.java.com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client;
import main.java.com.turn.ttorrent.client.SharedTorrent;
import main.java.com.turn.ttorrent.common.Torrent;
import main.java.com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.TrackedTorrent;
import main.java.com.turn.ttorrent.tracker.Tracker; 



// Create tracker instance
    Tracker tracker = new Tracker(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    // Load torrent file
    File torrentFile = new File("/path/to/torrentFile.torrent");
    // Create torrent instance
    TrackedTorrent torrent = new TrackedTorrent(Torrent.load(torrentFile, null));
    // Announce torrent
    tracker.announce(torrent);
    // Start the tracker
    tracker.start();

    torrentFile = new File(path + ".torrent");
    File downloadDir = new File("/path/to/torrents_download_dir");//unsure

    Client client = new Client(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), SharedTorrent.fromFile(torrentFile, downloadDir));
    // Add client.share(); if you wish to share the torrent infinitely
    client.run();
```

I'm getting this error message when I hover over load:

```
The method load(File, boolean) in the type Torrent is not applicable for the arguments (File, null)
```

I'm also unsure what I should place in `File downloadDir`.  I'm still a beginner and if someone could point me in the right direction to putting this into my program that would be great. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Learn to interpret the error messages. It's all right there. Load expects a boolean and you're giving it null.

Comment: I know how to interpret error messages. Before posting the question I tried setting it to false but it gave me the error message "The constructor TrackedTorrent(Torrent) is undefined". Also, the example given on the gitHub link provided by tTorrent had it as null. There was another person that posted the same answer as you and deleted it because we didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Torrent.load(torrentFile, null) wants a File object.

e.g

```
Torrent.load(new File(/foo/path.torrent), null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your objects and method in a main Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Object 1;
// Object 2;
```

}